# MoveTowars телепортирует объект?

Tags: unity3d

Скажите телепортирует ли метод MoveTowars объект?
Скажем мне нужно плавно переместить объект из точки а к точке b, при этом нельзя использовать телепортацию объекта.

```
        Vector3 a = transform.position;
        Vector3 b = new Vector3(5, 10, 10);

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(a, b, step);
        }
```

Корректный ли данный пример?

Comment: Кстати, почему нельзя использовать "телепортацию"? Что-то связанное с коллизиями?

Comment: @trollingchar просто одно из условий - "объекты не должны телепортироватся, Плавное перемещение", это меня и запутало) Физическое перемещение не используется.

Comment: Наверно, имелось в виду то, чтобы объект не за 1 такт туда попал. Я почему про коллизии спросил, это есть такая проблема с пролетанием объектов через стену, если у них большая скорость, я подумал что может быть из-за этого нельзя.

Comment: @trollingchar физически правильное движение - это тоже телепортация, единственное отличие от телепортации через Transform - физика учитывает преграды при телепортации.